# How to SELECT multiple columns dynamically in DolphinDB?

Tags: metaprogramming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

Below is part of my table schema.

[my table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rvc0.png)

I can use statement  `select factor.column(2) as code from factor` to get the second column.

I wonder if I can SELECT the 2nd column, and the 4th to the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Using metaprogramming is a good choice.

Get the column names of the table first using function `columnNames`.

Access column names by index and join them.

Create and execute a SQL statement using function `sql` and `eval` with the metacode generated by function `sqlCol`.

```
factor=table(2015.01.15 as date,`00000.SZ as code,-1.05 as factor_value,1.1 as factor01,1.2 as factor02)
colNames = factor.columnNames()
finalColNames = colNames[1] join colNames[3:]
sql(sqlCol(finalColNames), factor).eval()
```

---

```
code     factor01 factor02
-------- -------- --------
00000.SZ 1.1      1.2
```